# Laravel Elixir and Bower: Mixing javascript issue

Tags: laravel, bower, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I have my Bower vendor directory at `resources/assets/vendor`.

In my gulpfile, I've tried the following:

```
mix.scripts([
    "vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
], "public/js");
```

When I run `gulp` in terminal, it doesn't seem to do anything. No errors though.

I also tried this:

```
mix.copy('vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'public/js/jquery.js');
```

To no avail.

What am I missing?

## update & solution

Only sass,less and coffee scripts are by default looked for in `resources/assets/[sass/coffee/less]` while JS files are simply in `resources/js` which confused me. Beware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we don't know location of your `jquery.min.js` file. However the default location for scripts files is `resources/js` so to make it work, you should have your `jquery.min.js` file in `resources/js/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`.

As 2nd argument you should pass your target filename with path, so it should be for example:

```
mix.scripts([
    "vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
], "public/js/jquery.min.js");
```

assuming as I mentioned at the beginning you have this JS file in `resources/js/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` location

If you don't, you should use 3rd parameter. So in this case, if your JS file is really in "vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" location, you could use:

```
mix.scripts([
    "jquery.min.js"
], "public/js/jquery.min.js", "vendor/jquery/dist");
```

to make it work.

**EDIT**

After explaining in comments, you should use then:

```
mix.scripts([
    "vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
], "public/js/jquery.min.js", "resources/assets/js");
```

Comment: I have my jquery.min.js located at `resources/js/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` and nothing happens when I run `gulp` :\

Comment: @PetterThowsen So you should use the first code I showed, but as 2nd argument you need to pass filename and not just directory.

Comment: @PetterThowsen I've just checked it and the file was generated without a problem. Do you have any gulp information for example `starting gulp` etc ? You should also make sure that you have the newest Laravel elixir installed. You should consider removing `node_modules` folder and running again `npm install` to get fresh copy of all modules. (you should of course backup this directory just in case)

Comment: @PetterThowsen So you should probably doublt check if you have exact same code I have and you have this file in `resources/js/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` path without spaces, in the same letter case as provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71708/discussion-between-petter-thowsen-and-marcin-nabialek).